# Summarizing Mysql Table using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple mysql table I want to summarize. Here is my table

Table Name: `hauling_trip`

Columns:

```
ID, CONTRACTOR, HAULING_SHEET_NO, FROM_LOCATION, TO_LOCATION, LOAD_WEIGHT_KG, PASS_NO
```

Data:

```
1   PM  A00001  Stumping A  Pangkalan   940.00  112233
2   PM  A00002  Stumping B  Pangkalan   530.00  112233
3   PM  A00003  Stumping B  Pangkalan   970.00  112244
4   PM  A00004  Stumping A  Pangkalan   450.00  112244
5   TKF A00005  Stumping A  Pangkalan   850.00  112255
6   TKF A00006  Stumping B  Pangkalan   780.00  112255
7   TKF A00007  Stumping A  Pangkalan   903.00  112266
```

What I want to do is, I want to summarize this table by showing the total No of Trip and Load Weight (KG) of each PASS_NO. Here is the desired result

```
PASS_NO CONTRACTOR  WEIGHT_A    TRIP_A  WEIGHT_B    TRIP_B
112233  PM          940.00      1       530.00      0
112244  PM          450.00      0       970.00      1
112255  TKF         850.00      1       780.00      0
112266  TKF         903.00      1       0.00        0
```

Identical PASS_NO means, hauling sheets are assumed as 1 trip. For example, hauling sheet A00001 and A00002 have the same PASS_NO which is 112233. So both hauling sheets belong to 1 trip AND this trip is belong to FROM_LOCATION Stumping A because the weight is greater than Stumping B.

Here is the query I'm working on at the moment. But I can't figure out how to get the trip right.

```
SELECT
    a.PASS_NO,
    a.CONTRACTOR,
    ( SELECT sum( LOAD_WEIGHT_KG ) FROM hauling_trip WHERE PASS_NO = a.PASS_NO AND FROM_LOCATION = 'Stumping A' ) AS WEIGTH_A,
    ( SELECT count( PASS_NO ) FROM hauling_trip WHERE PASS_NO = a.PASS_NO AND FROM_LOCATION = 'Stumping A' ) AS TRIP_A,
    ( SELECT sum( LOAD_WEIGHT_KG ) FROM hauling_trip WHERE PASS_NO = a.PASS_NO AND FROM_LOCATION = 'Stumping B' ) AS WEIGHT_B,
    ( SELECT count( PASS_NO ) FROM hauling_trip WHERE PASS_NO = a.PASS_NO AND FROM_LOCATION = 'Stumping B' ) AS TRIP_B, 
    SUM(a.LOAD_WEIGHT_KG) AS TOTAL_WEIGHT
FROM
    hauling_trip AS a 
GROUP BY
    a.PASS_NO, a.CONTRACTOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ht.PASS_NO, ht.CONTRACTOR,
       sum(case when ht.from_location = 'Stumping A' then ht.load_weight_kg end) as weight_a,
       sum(ht.from_location = 'Stumping A') as trip_a,
       sum(case when ht.from_location = 'Stumping B' then ht.load_weight_kg end) as weight_b,
       sum(ht.from_location = 'Stumping B') as trip_b
       sum(ht.LOAD_WEIGHT_KG) AS TOTAL_WEIGHT
FROM hauling_trip ht
GROUP BY ht.PASS_NO, ht.CONTRACTOR
```

Comment: your query result is same like mine. how can I set a condition, IF weight_a > weight_b THEN trip_a=1, trip_b=0?